# How to display specific file on the internal storage in listview android?

Tags: android, listview, android-internal-storage

I saved some file in my app now I want to show the ones which are ended by .txt on my `listview` not all of them. Could you please help me?

[image: You can see all files in my screenshot, I want to show just .txt ones]

Here is how I generated my listview:

```
void ShowSavedFiles(){
    SavedFiles = fileList();

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                  SavedFiles);

    listSavedFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a source code of your solution, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
void ShowSavedFiles(){ArrayList<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<String>();
SavedFiles = fileList();

for(String str: SavedFiles) {
    if (str.trim().contains("_cred.txt")) {
                  filteredList.add(str.trim());}
     }
           ArrayAdapter adapter
                = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                filteredList);

        listSavedFiles.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `fileList` method to filter out other files, since it looks like the only data your adapter gets.

Comment: I tried this:

String  s = givenName +".txt";

        for( int i=0; i<SavedFiles.length; i++) {
            if (SavedFiles.equals(s)) {
                ShownFiles = SavedFiles;}
       }

But it doesn't work, do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a list with only filenames that ends with .txt, if you use Java 8 you can do it like this:

```
SavedFiles = fileList().stream()       // Convert list to stream
    .filter(fileName -> fileName.endsWith(".txt"))  // Filters filename to only keep ones that ends with ".txt"
    .collect(Collectors.toList());   // Then collect to a list
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

search for specific values and add them

```
    public void search(){

    List <String> listClone = new ArrayList<String>(); 
           for (String string : SavedFiles) {
               if(string.matches(".txt")){
                   listClone.add(string);
               }
           }
     }
```

update the `listview` using: `updatedData(listClone)`

```
 public void updatedData(List itemsArrayList) {

    adapter .clear(); 

    if (itemsArrayList != null){

        for (Object object : itemsArrayList) {

            adapter .insert(object, mAdapter.getCount());
        }
    }

    adapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Listing all the Specific type of Documents files in android from external storage to ListView widget.

```
ArrayList<String> filenames;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// onCreate method

filelist =  findViewById(R.id.fileList);  //filelist is ListView widget
    filenames = new ArrayList<>();
    getFiles();         //  files funtions
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filenames);
    filelist.setAdapter(adapter);

// getFiles() is method for getting and filtering all doccuments files from external storage

private void  getFiles() {

    File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String filename ;
    Queue<File> files = new LinkedList<>();         //Linklist

    files.addAll(Arrays.asList(path.listFiles()));  //adding all files of path in linklist

    while (!files.isEmpty()){
        File file = files.remove();
        if (file.isDirectory()){
            files.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));


        }
        else if (file.getName().endsWith(".doc")||file.getName().endsWith(".xls")||file.getName().endsWith(".ppt")){   //filtering files
            filename = file.getName();               // according to their extension
            filenames.add(filename);              //filenames is string ListArray

        }



    }


}
```

Just change string values like `.doc` or `.xls` to `.your_file_extension`